# (int) to evaluate $_GET

Tags: php

Is it secure to use (int) to make sure you are receiving a integer on the URL?

For example: `test.php?id=3`

```
if ((int)$_GET['id'] == 0) {
    echo 'Invalid Entry';
}
```

So if somebody enters other than a number it will be invalid.

Comment: ^ Or you can use [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: @Rizier123: Of course, that would allow floats and expressions like `+0123.45e6`too.

Comment: id wouldn't be "1.5", is_numeric wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, all I want is that if is different than a valid possible id number it would return as false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if (filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Invalid Entry';
}
```

Input / Output:

```
0        -> Good
"0"      -> Good
5        -> Good
"5"      -> Good
1.4      -> Bad
"1.4"    -> Bad
"12text" -> Bad
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want numbers <0 you can use this:

```
if (filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === FALSE || $_GET['id'] <= 0) {
    echo 'Invalid Entry';
}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use `===` rather than `==` here?

Comment: @developerwjk If you only use `==` then 0 would be invalid as int, with 3x `===` You don't get that and int 0 is valid (Because it returns the value if it is okay, so `0 == false` would be true)

Comment: Hello, thanks. It gives negative numbers as true as well

Comment: @Kitara You're welcome! (Yes negative numbers are also integers)

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 yeah, I agree, but negative numbers are not valid Id's :)

Comment: @Kitara Just add a OR statement and also check that it's not 0 or anything under it

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah that would work. One question, the FILTER_VALIDATE_INT will give me the same results as the ctype_digit? What is the difference? Performance?

Comment: @Kitara First it's a filter flag so with `filter_var()` you can filter different things. 2. with `ctype_digit()` a normal int is false with my method it would be good

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the Edit, and great explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ctype_digit for that http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

```
if (!ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'Invalid Entry';
}
```

Comment: Hi, this one accepts 0 as being true. So what I did was
if ((int)$_GET['id'] == 0 || !ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) { echo 'Invalid'; }

Comment: You shouldn't filter out the "0" as it's a valid int. If you are using this to retrieve data from your database, your query will just return an empty results set.

Comment: Hi @amrhady  agree it would return an empty results set, but if I can avoid a call to the database when know for sure it will return an empty set it would be one less stress to the database.